# How to change the size of the $_POST php array?

Tags: php, linux, post

I have a form with more than 1600 element so when I press the SUBMIT button some fields are not saved in my database , I make a little research and I found that in the new version of PHP they limit the size of $_POST array to 1000 element and they said that it is configurable.
I should change some variable in the php.ini.
I do not know how to reach that file in my Apache (Linux) server and I do not know what the variables to be changed.
Are they these variable? :

```
max_input_vars
max_input_nesting_level
```

I do not want to make a big problem online, my site will break down so anybody can help me , sorry my knowledge in Linux servers are not good at all?

Comment: Why do you have so many form elements?!?!

Comment: is a human filling in 1600 form fields on one page ?

Comment: some human and some not

Comment: break it in to multiple pages. sounds like torcher to me.

Comment: Why on Earth is there 1,600 elements?!

Comment: In your [`php.ini`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) generally,
or via [`.htaccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) for mod_php,
or even [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) with FastCGI setups.

Comment: I try to add this lines to htaccess but it give me internal server error

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to for you to add this to your .htaccess file

```
php_value max_input_vars 1600
```

Or whatever value you wish to allow.

Comment: I open my .htacsse file and it is empty i just add your line ,and it shows now an internal server error 500

Answer (score 0):

```
max_input_vars
```

it limits your number of inputs (thus, fields in your forms). Also

```
max_input_nesting_level
```

they are configurable. Just edit your php.ini or htaccess values.

Comment: i try to edit the htaccess but it give me unternal server error 500 when i run the page

Comment: the file just have the following line: php_value max_input_vars 1600